# How to remove my password using net user?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I'm currently using this code to try to remove my password

```
net user $env:username ""
```

If I run it in a cmd it works, not in powershell I get the same result as if I had typed :

```
net user $env:username
```

Which are the informations from last password change etc.

Do you have any idea ? I tried using [string]::Empty instead of the quotes, but the password was literally [string]::Empty and putting it in a variable didn't do the job

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe [Set-LocalUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/set-localuser?view=powershell-5.1) would work.

Comment: Previous answer from mhu is working pretty nicely, haven't checked for Set-LocalUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 net user $env:username `"`"
```